# ObjC - presentViewController breaks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, show, viewcontroller

I am trying to programmatically show another View Controller. I wrote some code that I learned from examples, it gives no errors. But it Breaks and shows this in green:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); thread 1 : signal SIGABRT
```

I used this code:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens probably because you don't have a **UIViewController** with Storyboard ID **secondViewController** in your storyboard.

You can drag a UIViewcontroller to your Storyboard and in Identity inspector set Storyboard ID to **secondViewController**.
See the image below

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my code that I did do this.

I Added "secondViewController" in the Storyboard ID of the UIViewController I want to go to already.

Comment: Can you share console log?